# Pure ALOHA acknowledgement messages on a busy channel

Tags: protocol-theory

I have a question about ALOHA protocol acknowledgement messages.

If host A sends a message to host E, and E sends an acknowledgement back to host A, but then it collides with a message being sent from another host, say, host C, then both messages end up being garbled. Does that mean host A will have to send his original message again, even though host E has already received it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host A, not receiving an ACK within a reasonable amount of time must assume that the original message was lost due to a collision. So, yes, it will re-transmit the original message.

There is a [PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEMQFjAFahUKEwir7rHRpLvIAhXDlYAKHWK-B_o&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.seas.upenn.edu%2F~kassam%2Ftcom370%2Fn99_12.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFlxDiFQZfEIAKX5mtY2LwzeknbRA&sig2=L4OrRe32bhnFvvnaqhRs-A&cad=rja) that explains how this works in Section 3:

> If a sending node does not see on the downlink within a reasonable
>   time an ACK for a frame it sent up, it assumes that a collision
>   occurred and re-transmits the frame after some random delay. Thus
>   ALOHA depends on the ability of a node to detect or learn that a
>   collision has occurred.